# Stata / Event Studies

Tags: for-loop, stata

I am currently running several event studies with a sample of 2836 companies. I regress each company's return on several factors (compiled by FF). Thus, I wrote the following loop:

```
 gen predicted_return4=.
 forvalues i = 1(1)2836 { 
 l id acq_company_id if id==`i' & dif==0
 reg ret ${ff} if id==`i' & estimation_window==1
 predict p4 if id==`i'
 replace predicted_return4 = p4 if id==`i' & event_window==1
 drop p4
 }
```

The loop works fairly well. However, after a few regressions an error arises (see below).

```
          +---------------+
          | id   acq_co~d |
          |---------------|
   48818. | 21          8 |
          +---------------+

  Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =     220
 -------------+------------------------------           F(  3,   216) =   53.77
   Model |  .012074753     3  .004024918           Prob > F      =  0.0000
Residual |  .016167584   216   .00007485           R-squared     =  0.4275
 -------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.4196
   Total |  .028242337   219   .00012896           Root MSE      =  .00865

  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ret |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
   mktrf |   .9786525    .119806     8.17   0.000     .7425141    1.214791
     smb |    .201586    .172118     1.17   0.243    -.1376599    .5408319
     hml |  -.1526954   .2606448    -0.59   0.559    -.6664282    .3610374
   _cons |   .0004081   .0005981     0.68   0.496    -.0007708     .001587
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(option xb assumed; fitted values)
(5800880 missing values generated)
(5 real changes made)
**no observations**
r(2000);
```

After checking the data, I did not find any missing observations. Is there anybody who already dealt with the same problem? Is there a way to avoid missing values respectively to ignore missing values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enough missings, you will get `error 2000`. You should want to trap that. Try something like

```
gen predicted_return4=.
forvalues i = 1(1)2836 { 
    l id acq_company_id if id==`i' & dif==0
    capture noisily reg ret ${ff} if id==`i' & estimation_window==1
    quietly if _rc == 0 { 
        predict p4 if id==`i'
        replace predicted_return4 = p4 if id==`i' & event_window==1
        drop p4
    } 
}
```